# ibm db2 multiple alter table statements

Tags: foreign-keys, db2

I am trying to run multiple alter table statements for adding foreign keys on my database

I am using RazorSQL

this are my sql statement

```
            ALTER TABLE SPO999.AVTVRSTEPLACILAPOD
        ADD CONSTRAINT SQL100419145030510 FOREIGN KEY
            (AVP_VRSTEPLACILA)
        REFERENCES SPO999.VRSTEPLACILA
            (VP_ID_VP)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        --ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ENFORCED
        ENABLE QUERY OPTIMIZATION;

    -- DDL Statements for foreign keys on Table SPO999.AVTVRSTEPLACILAVRPL

    ALTER TABLE SPO999.AVTVRSTEPLACILAVRPL
        ADD CONSTRAINT SQL100419145030630 FOREIGN KEY
            (AVV_VRSTEPLACILA)
        REFERENCES SPO999.VRSTEPLACILA
            (VP_ID_VP)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        --ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ENFORCED
        ENABLE QUERY OPTIMIZATION;
```

If I run one at a time it works, while if trying to run both at I get an SQL Error -104 a token,character or clause is invalid or missing.

I can not find a problem/solution

any suggestions?
thank you

Comment: What tool/program are you using to run the statements?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is likely that you can't have these two foreign key definitions referencing the same column within a single transaction.

Try adding `commit;` between the statements.

(Your SQL editor, depending on its settings, may automatically send a `commit` after each chunk of statements that you execute.  That would explain the difference between the two cases).